# Стилизвация маркера в списку ul li?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, вёрстка

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья!
Подскажите как сделать стилизация маркера списка (ul li)
Слева должен быть блок с такими стилями

```
 ul {
    list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul>li:before {
    content:"##";
    color:transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```